# printing iframe content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have an iframe:

```
<iframe name="printarea" id="printarea" src="print.php" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

i need this iframe to have the style "display: none;" so it is invisible

now when someone clicks a link generated via php:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="print_receipt('.$row['id'].'); return false;"><img src="images/icon-print.png" alt="" /></a>';
```

i want it to simply change the iframe SRC and print what is in the iframe, however my code is not working at all:

```
function print_receipt (id)
{
    $('#printarea').attr('src', 'print.php?id='+id);
    $('#printarea').focus();
    $('#printarea').print();
}
```

so this is what i want:
- user clicks on link
- iframe content changes based on the link he clicks
- iframe content prints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 issues:

1. you'll maybe need to wait until the page is loaded
2. print() is a method of window-objects

---

```
   $('#printarea')
    .load(function(){this.contentWindow.print();$(this).unbind('load');})
     .attr('src', 'print.php?id='+id);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What is `$('#printarea').focus();` supposed to achieve? As far as I know `.focus()` works with form elements and links...
2. What is `$('#printarea').print();`? Haven't come across that function in jQuery. If you're using a plugin it would help to mention which one.

So perhaps you'll have more luck with:

```
function print_receipt (id)
{
    $('#printarea')
       .attr('src', 'print.php?id='+id)
       .css("display","block");
}
```