# onclick print content which inside the iframe

Tags: jquery, html

i am facing the problem on print the content inside the iframe.

this is the anchor tag outside the iframe :

```
<a href=”#” onclick='window.print()' >Print</a>
```

HERE IS MY iframe

```
<iframe name="newtest"  src="https:xyz.com" ></iframe>
```

I want to print the page which is inside the iframe on click of anchor tag which is outside the iframe

Comment: check this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906047/printing-iframe-content-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<iframe src="" id="iframeid"></iframe>

document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.print();
```

if you are trying to print a remote site, you can't do it in any way.

if you are `http://yoursite.org` and the iframe is `<iframe src="http://google.com">` you can't do that, site domain must match

instead if the page is a local page `<iframe src="page.htm">` it will work

Comment: but i want to print the diffrent doamin ..any solution for this

Comment: it's impossible http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy unless you own the remote site that you are trying to print

Comment: @Wes If you own the iframe domain, add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the response header